# How do you set a variable Y-axis min/max?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a colleague who creates lots of charts.  He wants the min/max of the Y-axis of a bar chart to reflect the min/max within a range in Column "A" of an Excel spreadsheet.  The min/max will change depending on his input into the spreadsheet.  The values are very large and he has several hundred rows of values.

I would write a min() and max() formula or sort by ascending order to identify the upper and lower bounds, then change the axis options to "Fixed" for the Y-axis and type in the numbers.  He does not want to do this.  He also does not know VBA.

Is there a quick way to accomplish his goal without using VBA and without having to type in the Fixed min/max values?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for superuser.com ?

Comment: Okay, I will cross-post there.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is not a quick way to accomplish his goal without using VBA and without having to type in the Fixed min/max values.